# python button active backgroundcolor

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to save changes to a file, when it's not open the button must be green onclick and when it's open the button must be red onclick until I close the file. But I got the error that my tkinter button doesn't become red. Here is my code:

```
 tryit = True
        while tryit == True:
            try:
                wb.save(saved_file)
                save_to_file_button.config(activebackground="green")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                tryit = False
            except:
                save_to_file_button.config(activebackground="red")
                time.sleep(1.0)
                tryit = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an infinite loop in a GUI handler.  When you create or change a GUI element, nothing gets drawn.  Instead, that just sends a message to the component.  The messages are fetched and dispatched when the code gets back to the main loop.  As long as you are in your loop, Tk can't get back to its main loop, and your UI is frozen.

If you need periodic stuff like this, you need to use `root.after` to request a callback after some period of time.  For example (you didn't give enough details for me to fill in the correct names, but this is the idea):

```
    def savefile(self):
        try:
            wb.save(saved_file)
            save_to_file_button.config(activebackground="green")
        except:
            save_to_file_button.config(activebackground="red")
            root.after( 1.0, self.savefile)
```

It takes a different coding philosophy to work in an event-driven system.

Comment: but it definitely works also except the activebackground change: It stays in the while loop until you have closed the file. Your code works too but in a different way: (1.0 must be 1) And not after one click while the file is opened, but after 4 clicks the button stays red until I have closed the file! How can I edit it so that after 1 click the button stays red?

Comment: Perhaps you should take out the try/except to see what exception you're getting.  That's the problem which a global `except`; you never see the actual error.

Comment: I know what the error is: it is: permission denied, so it could not access the file because it is open and that is my intention, that I only save it when it's closed and that I can see it from my program instead of the console.